# AngularJS validation directive message arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Let's say we need a custom Angular validator that provides arguments to the error message.
For instance if we were to create a validator that would evaluate the minimum length of an array and when it was invalid the message should be "The minimum length is {0}".

Now considering we have created a custom directive(as the one provided below) for this validation, how do we provide the "{0}" argument from the validation directive function to the validation message?

Here's a custom validation directive for the that:

```
.directive('arrayLength', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.arrayLength = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return modelValue >= parseInt(attrs.arrayLength);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And here where we would be declaring the message:

```
.run([
    'defaultErrorMessageResolver',
    function (defaultErrorMessageResolver) {
        defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function (errorMessages) {
            errorMessages['arrayLength'] = 'Minimum length is {0}';
        });
    }
]);
```

So... any ideas?

I'm sure it's not a rocket science. It's just that I'm new to Angular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A plunker or jsfiddle to use running code?

Comment: Yes. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4tsc7gcf/14/  Just hit GO!! and notice the displayed message. the {0} arg is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Look this. Can pass the message on the own policy ("messageerror")

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

function Fiddle($scope) {}

app.directive('input', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            minlength: "@minlength"
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            
            elm.bind('keyup', function() {
                var valid = (this.value && this.value.length >= scope.minlength);
                if (!valid){
                    if(elm.parent().find("span").length == 0)
                        elm.parent().append("<span style='border:solid 3px #FE2E2E'>Min is " + scope.minlength + "</span>");
                }else
                    elm.parent().find("span").remove();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="Fiddle">
    <li>
      <label for="barthirty">Min 3 Char:</label>
      <input input-data type="datetime" ng-model="nmTest" minlength="3"/>

    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: not sure if i understood your code, but it seems to me that it is not passing the argument, but instead, the whole message. If so, that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: I pass the mensageerror on code for demonstrate as working with params in directive. Look now! In the example param is utilized for validate and show message

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, but still... not what I'm after. Your solution works, but is not providing a raw message. Instead, it's appending HTML. I've provided a fiddle( https://jsfiddle.net/4tsc7gcf/14/ ) so that it gives a better idea of what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey man, i look your sugestion in jsfiddle, but your idea is use the factory for create a 'validator data'. Right, is possible, however this is weird and not is common. The factory is used for create services common and shared with controllers. One exemple is service layer of acess rest service. For validate elements in view is common used directive, right? Then you can use one directive for validate multiple fields. So you use attribute in field for validate e show message error.